# Are we able to edit the schema of bigquery table after creation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, big-data

I made a mistake of specifying a field as integer instead of float.
I found that I am not able to make correction a field once the table is created. 
I have to delete and re-create the table again to make things right. 
Does anyone know of a better way to modify a field after a table is created?
Thanks.

Comment: After much trying, I am rather convinced that the only way is to delete and re-create.

Comment: This comment may irrelevant to you scenario. If you import using BigQuery WebUI you can click history and change column definition from the screen, then, re-import it. But if you are using `bq load` command with `--autodetect`, I cannot find the way to change schema definition. I often add `[<table_schema>]` after `bq load` command to indicate its schema. But once imported, I cannot find the way to edit table schema.

Comment: Another option to consider are using Dataprep or Cloud DataFlow to transform the table.

Comment: Looks you can not change the schema after creation of the table, but you can rename the columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395612/update-big-query-table-schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that you can not change the schema after creation of the table, but you can rename the columns by looking at the suggestions at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395612/update-big-query-table-schema

Answer (score 2):

The BigQuery Doesn't allow us to modify the table schema directly. Although we can add new columns using Web UI.
There are two way we can modify the Schemas after creation both of these approaches need us to recreate the table.

**Method 1**
**Using SQL:**

Write a SQL query in Query editor to Select all the required columns except the ones you want to modify.

Go to query Setting

Set Destination table having same as the Original one

Select write Preference as "Overwrite Table"

Save and run query.

**Method 2**
**Using CLI**
This is an elegant way to modify the existing Schema.

Run `bq show --schema --format=prettyjson project_id:dataset.table > schema_file` where you need to specify project, dataset and table path.

Define "schema_file" having .json format in above command.

Modify the Mode or Name in the Json file

Update the existing table using `bq update project_id:dataset.table schema`